# NodeJS Javascript - ChromeDriver - Script works fine in Windows. In Docker gives ElementNotFoundException

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an automation script which is in NodeJS JavaScript which uses chromedriver and selenium-webdriver. It runs perfectly fine in Windows but in Docker container it gives ElementNotFoundException. The chrome version and chromedriver version matches.

Following is the JavaScript file:

```
require("chromedriver");
const {By,Key,Builder} = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

 
async function functionA(){ 

        const url = "abcd.com";
    
        var cCode;
       //To wait for browser to build and launch properly
        let driver = await new Builder()
            .forBrowser("chrome")               
            
            .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments(['--no-sandbox','--headless', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']))                                  
            
            .build();
        
        await driver.get(url);
        
        const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        await wait(1 * 20 * 1000);
        await driver.manage().window().setRect({ width: 1552, height: 840 });
        await driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
        await driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abcd");
        var sName = await driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getText();
        console.log("sName is: " + sName);
        await driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();            
        
        //this.timeout(1.33 * 20 * 1000);
        await wait(1 * 20 * 1000);
        
        
        //It is always a safe practice to quit the browser after execution
        await driver.quit();
        //console.log(cCode);
        return 'some code;
    
}
 
async function testFunctionA()
{
    var result = await functionA();
    console.log(result);
}
testFunctionA();
```

Above script is called through a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash    
v=$(node ./test/executeScript.js)
echo "$v"
```

This shell script is called through docker:

```
FROM timbru31/node-chrome
USER root
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
RUN apt-get update
RUN mkdir /data
COPY . /dataRUN npm --prefix /data install
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN google-chrome --product-version
ADD /test /data/test
ADD /load-test /data/load-test
RUN ls -a
RUN SAUTH=$(sh /data/bashScript.sh)
```

Now when I run this docker file, I get the following exception

```
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="emailInput"]"}
(Session info: headless chrome=96.0.4664.93)
at Object.throwDecodedError (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:517:15)
at parseHttpResponse (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:643:13)
at Executor.execute (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:569:28)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async Driver.execute (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:732:17)
at async toWireValue (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:140:15)
at async /data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:190:16
at async forEachKey (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:184:9)
at async convertKeys (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:189:3)
at async Driver.execute (/data/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:730:22)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Command-line options | Node.js v17.2.0 Documentation
```

Please note that the javascript works perfectly fine in windows. All issues are encountered in docker.
What could be the possible reason and solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: I guess you should set the driver window sizes to big enough. The default screen size in headless mode is quite small

Comment: All the  RUN commands are run during the building of the container not during the execution.  SAUTH won't be available when you execute the actual script. Not sure if that matters, since it doesn't seem to be used in your JavaScript.